# How can I add Multiple Time dimensions on the same Google Data Studio chart?

Tags: looker-studio

I would like to check if it's possible to plot more than one time-dimensions in a Google Data Studio chart, preferably a [time series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) (line) chart. I'm having a lot of trouble to represent different information in the same chart through Google Data Studio.

I want to represent a sales cycle, that has 8 stages, meaning that most of them does not occur in the same day. All of them are related to one client/user. I've treated the data so I have this information separated, as I'm able to use it and create different and separated graphs - my intention, although, is to create one common graph with the time dimension not necessarily related to the other DateTime metrics.

Data set ([Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ctc_afQyKMJ_w9CTD1dMgO67TmnSjRVMaACSgCLrFQY/edit?usp=sharing)):

| Client ID (string) | Sign in at (date) | Commercial Approval at (date) | Commercial Approved (string) | Contract signed at (date) | Contract signed (string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03/12/2021 | 05/12/2021 | A | 06/12/2021 | A |
| B | 03/12/2021 |  |  |  |  |
| C | 04/12/2021 | 05/12/2021 | C | 07/12/2021 | C |
| D | 05/12/2021 | 06/12/2021 | D |  |  |
| E | 06/12/2021 | 06/12/2021 | E |  |  |

The result I want to achieve (hand-made, on the PowerPoint):

[image: desired graph hand-made]

[Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/a78e58dd-0ddc-4f43-b1ba-90c46c4c4413) result I'm achieving:

[image: setup_tab_3_charts]

Google Data Studio makes me choose one of the Date dimensions as the dimension. For example, if I chose the *Signed at* as a dimension and choose the period as between (including) *04/12/2021* and *06/12/2021*, then Google Data Studio will group the Clients by *Signed at*, and overlook the activities by those that Signed at *03/12/2021*.

Answer (score -2):

You should try linking the two sources directly through the date's, and not choose any other dimension, only as metrics! This worked for me, but unfortunately I can't replicate it for another project.

It is worth a try anyway.

Looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yArBN.png)

Comment: The instructions are unclear and the answer predominalty relies on an image (which references fields that the not cited in the question), Additionally, the statement "_ but unfortunately I can't replicate it for another project_" points towards this answer being one that is **Not Reproducible or Caused by a Typo**